# What is the term for "grounded" in the sense of a punishment?

Tags: word-requests

Children are often punished by their parents by not allowing them to go out.

In English, we call this action *grounding* and the child is *grounded*.

Is this a similar punishment in Japan? And what is it called?

Comment: http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%A4%96%E5%87%BA%E7%A6%81%E6%AD%A2

Comment: @shoko, please post as an answer.

Comment: 西洋では、「家から出さない」のが罰。日本では、逆に「家に入れない」のがこどもに対する罰。この違いはデカい。わかるかな？無理だろうなあ。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the term for “grounded” in the sense of a punishment?

In Japanese, we call that [外出禁止]{がいしゅつきんし}.

> Is this a similar punishment in Japan?

No. In Japan parents often punish their (usually young) children by locking them out of the house.